# Override default connection string

Tags: c#, connection-string

In an MVC web application I want to override connection strings based on the development machine I'm using. I can use Web.config transformations, but I also need to override connection strings in various non-web config files. I can use the [SlowCheetah extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5), but then I will end up creating the same transformation for every project that accesses the database. This is a hassle to maintain when the project becomes bigger and has more developers.

What I would like to do is modify the way Entity Framework or ASP.NET look for connection strings, adding a class of my own that looks for connection strings, and only implement the transformation logic once. I would hopefully use Ninject to inject it only when relevant.

Is there such an "IConnectionStringProvider" interface I can implement and register, and automagically have ASP.NET and EF use it?

EDIT. I have found [this](http://williablog.net/williablog/post/2010/03/29/Override-Configuration-Manager.aspx), but it seems real nasty. If there's no cleaner way, I'll just use multiple identical configuration translations, and maybe let the source control system duplicate them properly.

Answer (score 1):

You can tell Entity Framework to use a different connection string - it doesn't have to use the default one in web.config.

Here is an example: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/234677/Set-the-connection-string-for-Entity-Framework-at

Here is another: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738533.aspx

It's up to you how you architect the rest of it.

Personally I use an app setting in web.config to tell my code which connection string to use for a particular part of the system, e.g.

```
var connectionStringNameForMyFeature = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connectionStringNameForMyFeature"];

myFeature.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[connectionStringName];
```